# paypal android SDK integration with my app is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Hi i am trying to integrate Paypal **AndroidSDK** with my android application. i followed the paypal integration document and tried to integrate as per the instructions. But when i press **Buy** button screen is navigate to paypal screen which displayed below.
[image]

But onActivityResult call back is coming with **resultCode** as **0(RESULT_CANCELED)** immediately when i pressed the buy button instead of **RESULT_OK** after finishing the payment process with **PaymentConfirmation** results.

Following is my code snippet.

```
  public void initPaymentService() {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);

        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT, CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT);
        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, CONFIG_CLIENT_ID);

    //  intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RECEIVER_EMAIL, CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL);

        startService(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public void onBuyPressed(String amount) {
    PayPalPayment thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("1.75"), "USD", "hipster jeans");

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT, CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, CONFIG_CLIENT_ID);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RECEIVER_EMAIL, CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL);

    // It's important to repeat the clientId here so that the SDK has it if Android restarts your 
    // app midway through the payment UI flow.
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, "AL7neK4uQk1xTc-YsELHpTAvdkjscvGNJDGHhashc8BLL8nkaTesRWkHOczSmqMkKT"); // **Clientid** from **developer.paypal.com**
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYER_ID, "testpaypal@gmail.com");

    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

     if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
        if (confirm != null) {
            try {
                Log.i("PaypalTestActivity", confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));

                // TODO: send 'confirm' to your server for verification.
                // see https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/
                // for more details.

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("PaypalTestActivity", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Log.i("PaypalTestActivity", "The user canceled the Transaction.");
    }
    else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_PAYMENT_INVALID) {
        Log.i("PaypalTestActivity", "An invalid payment was submitted. Please see the docs.");
    }
}
```

initPaymentService() method call is from **onCreate** if my Activity.
My button is in a fragment and activity is inherited from FragmentActivity in v4 support library.

please let me know what i am doing wrong, why onActivityResult is getting called immediately instead of onCompletion of the payment process with confirmation Info.

Please let me know if you know the solution for my issue.
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i found the solution.

**PayPal androidSDK** integration is not working if the Current(where i placed Buy button) activity's **android:launchMode="singleInstance"**. when i removed the **launchMode** to that activity its working fine.

Comment: Thank you so much. I looked for the wolf. Regarding my environment i used "SingleTop" instead.

Comment: raj if you found the solution please help me am also plan to integrate pay pal account to android app for on-line business. business account from India.where can integrate details and get client id and secrete.

Comment: please follow https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/

Comment: @Raj please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154296/paypal-is-not-working-for-andriod-but-working-in-magento-site)